# Logout from the page with required fields in form (html5)

Tags: php, html, required

I have a button 'logout' on each page in the header and from simple pages session can be closed easily, but from the page with required fields HTML5 it prevents logging out.

Is it possible to solve this issue but to leave the fields with required? 

Or do I have to validate the fields through PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: Some code would help us out...

Comment: That could only be the case if your logout button was part of the form that has the required fields … so take it out of there.

Comment: Oh my inattention! I took it out of there and now it works. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Ass CBroe already pointed out in the comments:

You have to take the Button out of the html-form that has form validation. Separate html-forms for separate formular.